# setWindowFlag(Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint) not working on Centos

Tags: c++, qt

I am opening a form window and wants to stay it on top always whether it is focused or not , i am using this function `setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)` of QT it is working fine on Mac as i desire but when i use the same function on centos it doesn't work correctly and window hides when not focused

Comment: I have solved this problem by just adding another flag in the function

Comment: setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint )

Comment: Don't answer in comments, add your solution as a proper answer.

Comment: sorry for adding in comments ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by just adding another flag in the function

setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint )