# setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11ByPassWindowsManagerHint) on Linux

Tags: qt

I want my Qt form to always stay active and remain on top whether it is active or not by using this function  `setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11ByPassWindowsManagerHint)` my window always stays on top which i want but the problem is that On Mac it is working fine but on Centos it becomes border less and no close minimize maximize button is shown 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the cause of your problems, but you need to add those flags to the existing ones, instead of replacing them. ie,
`setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11ByPassWindowsManagerHint);`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setWindowFlag(Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint) not working on Centos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339880/setwindowflagqtdialog-qtwindowstaysontophint-not-working-on-centos)

Comment: Seems to be the same question you asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339880/setwindowflagqtdialog-qtwindowstaysontophint-not-working-on-centos